# download image using php form

Tags: php, download

I need to Download the particular image from page using submit button, so i am using form and php submit action, Here my html and php code

HTML Code

```
<form name="logo" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="lgpath" value="images/logo/<?php echo $SelPro['lgpat'];?>">
    <img src="images/cmplogo/<?php echo $SelPro['lgpat'];?>">               
    <div><input type="submit" value="<?php echo $SelPro['lgname'];?>" name="dwnlg" id="dwnlg"></div></div>
    </form>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
    if($_POST['dwnlg'])
    {
        $LgPath=$_POST['lgpath'];
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$LgPath.'"');
    }
?>
```

i gave path to download the image to header but it's only downloaded that current page as file, how can i solve it?

Comment: Your display image path and hidden image path are different. Verify that first.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code to download

```
<?php 
    if($_POST['dwnlg'])
    {
        $LgPath=$_POST['lgpath'];
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");  
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$LgPath.'"');  
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($LgPath));
        readfile($LgPath);  
     }
?>
```

In content type :

```
         if your image is in png format then it will be :
         header("Content-type: image/png");
         if your image is in jpeg format then it will be :
         header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

Comment: in filename we need to give basename function? because this code also download the current page not image.

Comment: i got the image, but one thing , i am paste my submit action script in image folder so that it's working. but if i give the image path  on image showing page it's downloaded current page only why like this coming???

Answer (score 0):

Setting the header just tells the client what the data is and what to do with it, it doesn't send the data.

You can use [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to do that

```
<?php
    if($_POST['dwnlg'])
    {
        $LgPath=$_POST['lgpath'];
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$LgPath.'"');
        readfile($LgPath);
    }
?>
```